# "Could not make plist file '/file/path/to/plist' writable" error message for Xcode Maven Build

Tags: ios, xcode, maven-plugin, pom.xml, auto-build

I'm trying to create a Maven project in order to build Xcode app (By using [Xcode Maven Plugin](http://sap-production.github.io/xcode-maven-plugin/site/examples/AppBuildExample.html)). Here is my pom.xml file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
                      http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>my.package</groupId>
  <artifactId>MyAppName</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>xcode-app</packaging>

  <build>
    <plugins>
          <plugin>
             <groupId>com.sap.prd.mobile.ios.mios</groupId>
             <artifactId>xcode-maven-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>1.14.0</version>
             <extensions>true</extensions>
             <executions>
                <execution>
                   <id>package-xcode-project</id>
                   <phase>package</phase>
                   <goals>
                      <goal>package-xcodeproj</goal>
                   </goals>
                </execution>
             </executions>  
          </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

I get the following error when I try mvn clean install:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.sap.prd.mobile.ios.mios:xcode-maven-plugin:1.14.0:change-versions-in-plist (default-change-versions-in-plist) on project MyAppName: Could not make plist file '/file/path/to/plist/MyAppName-Info.plist' writable. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured out the problem. In my project name I had space character and that causes this problem. I recreated my iOS application without any space in it's name and it works like a charm.